# Finding the optimal cutpoint using 'OptimalCutpoints' package

Tags: r, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I use the `OptimalCutpoints` package to determine the optimal cutpoint in probability predictions in an imbalanced binary classification problem. I select the `NO` class as healthy  class (the majority of the dependent variable is a `NO`). With the code I try to extract the optimal cutpoint to balance the sensitivity and specificity of the predictions. My question is, should I assume that the probability predicted by the model should be larger or smaller than the optimal cutpoint to classify it as a `YES`. This might be a simple question, however, on my dataset with different models I have observed that some times I gest better results by taking >= and other times <=.

```
optimal_cutpoint <- optimal.cutpoints(
        X = "score",
        status = "true",
        tag.healthy = 'NO',
        methods = "MaxSpSe",
        data = data.frame(score = predict(model, df_train, type="prob")$YES
                          , true = df_train$y),
        control = control.cutpoints()
    )
optimal_cutpoint <- optimal_cutpoint$MaxSpSe$Global$optimal.cutoff$cutoff[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the package documentation:

"... individuals with a test value lower than the cutoff are classified as healthy (negative test), whereas patients with a test value greater than (or equal to) the cutoff are classified as diseased (positive test)."

So in your example, probabilities below the cutpoint should be categorized as NO.

Answer (score 0):

### **Explanation:**

The difference that you find between using the conditional `>=` and `<=` is just a logical difference. A conditional `<=` is also equivalent to a strict `>`.

### **Example:**

`If`**`(a >= 2)`**`then "non-healthy"`
`If`**`(a <= 2)`**`then "healthy"`, also equivalent to say `if`**`(a > 2)`**`then "non-healhty"`